# Linearization of $ m \dfrac{dy^2}{dt^2} = u(t) - C_d \left( \dfrac{dy}{dt} \right)^2-mg $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

$$ m \frac{dy^2}{dt^2} = u(t) - C_d \left( \frac{dy}{dt} \right)^2-mg $$

where 
$$\begin{align*}
y(t)&=\text{missile altitude}\\
u(t)&= \text{force}\\
m&= \text{mass}\\
C_d&= \text{aerodynamic drag coefficient}
\end{align*}$$
How do I linearize this beast? I want to obtain a transfer function so that I can create a PID controller for it..

I'm really stumped and could use some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to design a PID controller for a nonlinear system based on linearization, the first step is to have to set an operation point for the altitude $x_1^*$, and another operation point for the velocity $x_2^*$.

Rewrite your system in state variable form

$$
\dot{x}_1 = x_2 \\
\dot{x}_2 = -\frac{C_d}{m}x_2^2 -g + \frac{u}{m}
$$
, where $x_1$ is the altitude and $x_2$ is the velocity. In matrix form

$$
\begin{bmatrix}\dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{x}_2 \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 &  -\frac{C_d}{m}x_2\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\x_2\end{bmatrix} 
+ \begin{bmatrix}0 \\  \frac{u}{m} - g\end{bmatrix} \\
y = Ix
$$

I have assumed here that you can observe both, altitude and velocity.

Then, you have to compute the Jacobian of the system evaluated at your operation points (you will realize that the altitude does not matter), and you will have your constant matrices A, B, C and D.

To compute the desired transfer function, you can check the equivalences here [State Space Representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_space_representation)

Note that your PID is only valid for a neighborhood about your desired velocity. I.E. you want to keep your desired velocity starting from this desired velocity, and not from another velocity.

Comment: Ah thanks.. I don't understand the last note though. Do you mean that as long as my initial velocity doesn't change, the linearization is valid? Because the initial velocity should always be zero in this case.. (The system is a missile)

Comment: The linearization is only valid about a small neighborhood of your operation point, because it is nothing else more than a Taylor's expansion about this point. If you want to go from 0 to 100m/s, and you design the PID for the linearization. Then you should compute the differences between the nonlinear system and the linear one for that range. If they are "close" enough, then your PID will have almost the same effect in the nonlinear system as in the linearization.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thanks